# How to evaluate complex expression in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to turn this code:

```
if obj[:id]
  begin
    foo = JSON.parse(obj[:foo])
    if ! foo['bar']
      something_is_off = true
    end
  rescue JSON::ParserError
    something_is_off = true
  end
else
  something_is_off = true
end
```

into something of the following kind:

```
something_is_off = ...
```

Is this possible with ruby?

Comment: Do you mean `foo['bar']` instead of `field['bar']`?

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
something_is_off = ! obj[:id] or ! begin
                                     foo = JSON.parse obj[:foo]
                                     ! foo['bar']
                                   rescue JSON::ParserError; end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did:

```
something_is_off = lambda {
  return true unless obj[:id]
  begin
    foo = JSON.parse(obj[:foo])
  rescue JSON::ParserError
    return true
  end
  ! foo['bar']
}.call
```

Answer (score 1):

Also the previous answers are absolutely correct, it’s not necessary to introduce new `foo` variable:

```
something_is_off = !(obj[:id] && JSON.parse(obj[:foo])['bar']) rescue true
```

Actually, `something_is_off` is false if and only an *obj* has an `:id` and `obj[:foo]['bar']` evaluates to true. So, [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: It is a long-standing conundrum for the Ruby core team how to make inline `rescue` recognize only specific exceptions. I suggested a new keyword `resc` for this, but it was rejected. Your solution sacrifices the specificity to `JSON::ParserError`, which goes beyond simple syntactic simplification requested by the OP. Moreover, your solution does not assign `foo` local variable. Maybe the asker's code relies on it somwhere later...

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Whether the `foo` local is needed it might be easily assigned inline: `(foo = JSON.parse(obj[:foo]))['bar']`. For handling `JSON::ParserError`, I dropped the note. While the question is “how to turn the code info `is_off=...` there is no need to handle the specific exception. Moreover, the shown code hints that the case “`obj` has no key `:foo`” should be handled as `is_off = true`.

Comment: Don't take it personal. Those are just my anal retentive feelings about refactoring a snippet whose context I don't know =)

Comment: Um, I didn't get why there's no need to handle the specific exception. And where does the code hint that absence of key `:foo` should result into `something_is_off == true`? Anyways, those are of no importance here.

Comment: @x-yuri I simply guessed that `something_is_off` should be `true` (off) by default. It should be enabled if and only we could retrieve the value from `json.foo.bar` and the latter evaluates to false. Whether there is no way to retrieve the value, and/or _something goes wrong_, the feature should be disabled (off.) It means, there is no reason to handle specific exception; any exception should set it to `true` (off.) That’s achieved by generic `rescue` handler.

Comment: @x-yuri, don't believe mudasobwa. You don't have control over the implementation of `JSON.parse` method, and there are types of exceptions that you should definitely not swallow by using the lazy man's inline `rescue`. Inline rescue is only for the cases where you _know_ that only such and such exception can happen, for example when you use built-in methods, as in `array.fetch( 1 ) rescue "oops"`. Technically speaking, your code is right to fish specifically for `JSON::ParserError`, and mudasobwa is being too sloppy replacing it with inline `rescue`.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Generally, I agree with you. That's why I'm catching one particular exception. But I don't see what can go wrong in this particular case. Moreover, things might go wrong even if we were catching only `JSON::ParserError`. Imagine they've come up with `JSON::RecoverableParserError` or something along those lines. I'm not so sure I'd like to let it go. So it's about choosing between two evils. Moreover, the intention to be conveyed is indeed if we can get to this `bar` value. And mudasobwa's version conveys it better then ours.

Comment: `and there are types of exceptions that you should definitely not swallow by using the lazy man's inline rescue` What can those be in this particular case? I believe inline `rescue` catches only `StandardError` and its descendants.

Comment: As a general rule, you should [rescue the most specific exception you can handle](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/rklemme/003-The_Universe_between_begin_and_end.html). In other words, rescue only those exceptions which you expect. If an exception that you do not expect occurs, you want to be informed about it. `StandardError` is not specific enough. Why do you think the programmer bothered to define a custom `JSON::ParseError` exception? Exactly for cases like yours. (Now that's theory. In practice, we are lazy and tired and we do end up using inline `rescue` often.)

Comment: @x-yuri, to be more particular. Imagine that an idiot comes and redefines `JSON.parse` method. Or redefines something that `JSON.parse` relies on. You want to know about that. You don't want your code to pretend that `JSON.parse` is sane an is just having problems with the input. That will delay your problem discovery. But even if `JSON.parse` is sane, its implementation is not your concern. `JSON::ParseError` is a part of its interface. When `JSON.parse` raises something else, you know that something is doubly off and you want to be informed about that.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Okay, let's not have accepted answer here then.

Comment: @x-yuri It’s completely up to you to decide what you want to handle. Whether you want to debug `JSON` library, you are completely right. Whether you want to achive your goals (assuming you are currently working on your own project and not implementing ruby core functionality,) you are free to spit on errors. The code should do what you expect. Whether you expect your application to crash with unknown exception while it _simply was not able to read secondary parameter from config file_ — it’s up to you :)